# differential equation with Dirac delta function as non-homogeneous term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can the equation $$-y''=\delta(x),\quad y(-2)=y(+3)=0$$ be solved? I tried $y_1''=0$ for $x<0$ and $y_2''=0$ for $x>0$ but did not get the constants $k_1$, $k_2$ in my answer $y_1(x)=k_1(x+2)$ for $x<0$ and $y_2(x)=k_2(x-3)$ for $x>0$.

Comment: When you need to write double ticks, type double ticks; don't use quotation marks because LaTeX things you want quotation marks formatted as if you were writing a quotation.

Comment: The solution set is $-x 1_{x > 0} + ax+b$  where $x 1_{x > 0} = \int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \delta(x_2)dx_2 dx_1$

Answer (score 1):

The equation $y'' = -\delta$ has particular solution $y_p(x)=-\frac12 |x|$. Then add the homogeneous solutions $y_h(x) = Ax+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants. Determine $A$ and $B$ from the conditions $y(-2)=y(3)=0$.

If you solve it by solving the two equations $y_1''=0$ for $x<0$ and $y_2''=0$ for $x>0$ then you get $y_1(x)=A_1x+B_1$ and $y_2(x)=A_2x+B_2$. Then, since you don't have $\delta'$ in the right hand side, the full solution shall be continuous, which forces $B_1=B_2$, which reduces one degree of freedom. And since you shall have $y''=-\delta$ you shall have $y'(0+)-y'(0-) = A_2-A_1 = 1$ which reduces another degree of freedom. Now you only have two degrees of freedom left, and the conditions $y(-2)=y(3)=0$ takes away those.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: choose $k_2$ such that $y(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$, then compute $y''(x)$.